# Backbone event bus & multiple views on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

I've got a problem, I try to use a simple backbone events bus

```
var eventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

And I've got an buttons below multiple Views in DOM, and the buttons are another view, like this:

```
===================
===== CONTENT =====  <- VIEW 1 (content)
===================
BTN1 | BTN2 | BTN3   <- VIEW 2 (controls)
```

And this repeats multiple times on a page.

The problem is, that when i trigger an event, it triggers for all Views on the page.

in 'controls' I've got:

```
events: {
    'click .check': 'checkMe',
}

checkMe: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    eventBus.trigger('checkMe');
}
```

and in all views:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    …
    eventBus.on('checkMe', this.checkMe, this);
},

checkMe: function() {
    alert("!");
}
```

As I said before, when I click in a one group of a buttons, It fires event for every single view (content) I've got on a page, is there any way to get this working in a proper way?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few of options occur to me.

---

You could [namespace your events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on). If each view has a unique id you could wire up the events like this:

```
eventBus.trigger('checkMe:' + uniqueId);
```

later catching it like this in the view

```
eventBus.on('checkMe:' + this.id, this.checkMe, this);
```

---

Or you could trigger the event with the uniqueId as a parameter

```
eventBus.trigger('checkMe', {id: uniqueId});
```

handling the event like this:

```
checkMe: function(params) {
    if(params.id === this.id) {
        alert("!");
    }
}
```

---

A third option might be creating a controller object to mediate between each set of content and controls. The controllers would serve as the event buses, each handling the controllers events discretely, preventing the global-event problem.

```
---------------------------------------------
| ===================                       |
| ===== CONTENT =====  <- VIEW 1 (content)  | <- Controller Instance
| ===================                       |
| BTN1 | BTN2 | BTN3   <- VIEW 2 (controls) |
---------------------------------------------
```

Let's say you have a collection that you iterate over to create the content/control sets.
It would look something like this (in very rough form.) The controller here is simply an event bus, but could hold more logic as needed.

```
collection.each(function(item) {
    var controller = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
    controller.onCheckMe = function () {
      contentView.performWork();
    };

    var contentView = new ContentView({
        performWork: function () {
            // TODO: do work here
        }
    });

    var controlsView = new ControlsView({
        events: {
            'click .check': 'checkMe',
        },
        checkMe: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.trigger('checkMe');
        }
    );

    controller.listenTo(controlsView, 'checkme', controller.onCheckMe.bind(controller));

    // TODO: render the views here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tell me something more about controller, in fact I have some kind of controller that creates all instances (views, collections etc) based on downloaded JSON (through getJSON). It will be very helpful!

Comment: Not knowing all the details I've added a guess about how you might use a controller for each item in the collection.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful! I resolved this by just passing eventBus into Views constructors (as there are only two), and It works, think that for this situation It's enough :).